# Removing Submit for approval button once the record is approved

Tags: apex, approval-process, approval-step, approve-action

I have an object that contains a checkbox field, whenever the checkbox is updated to true, submit for approval button should be removed.

Eg: If the Record Sent for approval is approved, it should not show the button submit for approval for the second time or for resubmitting.

Comment: Hi Samanya, Did you try exploring Dynamic form concept where you can apply filters for your buttons.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to hide this button.

1. Using lightning app builder - Add condition to display Submit for approval button. You can have a back end checkbox or status to hide this button.
2. Create new record type and new page layout without Submit for approval button. Once submitted for approval, update record type.

I would recommend 1st one, as it is straight forward.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comments earlier you can explore the option of Dynamic forms in lightning record pages where you can hide the button based on some conditions. Please find the [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dynamic_forms_overview.htm&language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5) for the Dynamic forms.

we have an [idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdghVUAR/approval-process-removal-of-submit-for-approval-button-after-a-record-is-app) for the same where customers were requesting same option to hide the submit for approval button once the record is approved